# Set QIcon() from URL in pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to bulk fetch multiple images list for `QListWidgetItem()`, However I still can't figure how to set `QIcon()` from URL.

I tried with `QPixmap()` however `setIcon()` refused and return error:

> TypeError: setIcon(self, QIcon): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPixmap'

Also i tried with `setPixmap()` but `QListWidgetItem()` refused and return error:

> AttributeError: 'QListWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'setPixmap'

Here is my full code:

```
# Fetch data
latestdata = get_data()
for data in latestdata:
    thumb = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
    thumb.setText(data['title'])
    image = QtGui.QIcon()
    # image.loadFromData(requests.get(data['img']).content) < still not figured how to with QIcon
    thumb.setIcon(image)
    self.MyLatestPhoto.addItem(thumb)
```

My expectation will like this:
[Photos aplication example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMBKh.png)

Any solution or alternative for showing photo thumbnails from URL?

Comment: You need to create a QPixmap first, *then* call `loadFromData()` and *finally* create a QIcon with that. Note that `requests.get` is blocking and shouldn't be used in the main thread of a UI environment. You either use a QThread (that emits the data or a QImage, **not** a QPixmap) or QNetworkAccessManager, and in both cases icons will be loaded asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks it works!
Also yes i noticed requests blocking main thread UI, will try QThread now. Thanks for tips!